# Display variable product stock availability on Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, product, archive

let's assume that a product has four sizes from 1 to 4
I want if the number of each of these variables is less than specified, a text is written on the product archive page.
For example, if variable 2 was less than 3 numbers, it should be written that there are less than 3 numbers left of size 2!

I don't know how to implement this so that if the number of products is below a certain limit, this message will be displayed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.